# How to understand the 1D tensor's direction in Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have three tensors a, b, c

```
a = torch.tensor([1,2])
b = torch.tensor([3,4])
c = b.view(2,1)
```

Now If I do  a @ b == a @ c it return tensor([True])
when I check b.shape c.shape, and they are different.

My question is what is the direction of the 1D tensor, is it vertical or horizontal?
whether it is vertical or horizontal, a @ b should not work without b's transpose.

How to understand the 1D dimension's direction in Pytorch? is shape(3) same as shape(3,1) ?

Or shape(3) could be either shape(3,1) or shape (1,3)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, `a` and `b` are 1D tensors which means they are **vectors**. These vectors are in a 2 dimensional space. vector `a` has `x=1` and `y=2`.
`a@b` is product of vector `a` and `b`.

```
a@b = a[0]*b[0] + a[1]*b[1] = 1*3+2*4 = 11
```

which 11 is a scalar. But `c` is a matrix and its product is:

```
a@c = a[0]*c[0] + a[1]*c[1] = 1*[3]+2*[4] = [11]
```

if you compare these results in torch you have:

`a@b == a@c` is equal to `torch.tensor(11)==torch.tensor([11])` which the result is `tensor([True])`

Answer (score 0):

a, b both are vectors(1st order tensor) of size 2. Vector multiplication is possible as long as both have same size.

```
a = torch.tensor([1,2])
b = torch.tensor([3,4])
print(a.shape)
print(b.shape)

#Output:
#torch.Size([2])
#torch.Size([2])
```

c is reshaped into a matrix(2nd order tensor) of shape (2x1).
dot product is possible between a vector and matrix with valid sizes.

```
c = b.view(2,1)

print(a.shape) #torch.Size([2])
print(c.shape) #torch.Size([2,1])

print(a@c) # possible 
print(c@a) # not possible, will throw error of size mismatch.
```